# add new line for swt plugin description in feature.xml

Tags: plugins, swt, newline

I am trying to add a multiline description for my plugin in feature.xml. I am trying by inserting  \n between the lines but does not seem to work.However I have seen a lot of plugins with multi-paragraph description. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It isn't clear from this exactly what description you are asking about (there are several). Is this the information displayed in the Installation Details dialog? Which tab of that dialog?

Comment: Hi greg,Yes, it is the information displayed in desccription while installing

Comment: Which tab of the installation Details dialog?

Comment: I dont think there are multiple tabs in that dialog. It comes in the 'install details' page . Specifically, I mean the 'Details' textfield that  displays the information about a plugin on click of it.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand which dialog you are asking about.  How exactly are you opening this dialog?

Comment: It is the  install new software dialog in eclipse .When I try to install my plugin Help> install new software > select plugin > Next. This navigates to install deatails page wher there will be list of installables listed.On click of each item the description is shown in 'details' textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New lines in the various fields in the `feature.xml` are generally done by using the NLS support and specifying the text in a `feature.properties` file.

So a description in the feature.xml would be:

```
<description>
  %description
</description>
```

and in the feature.properties

```
description=line 1\n\
line 2\n\
last line
```